# ondisconnect() is not working. user status in firebase database is remaining true even after getting disconnected from internet

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

**ondisconnect() is not working. user status in firebase database is remaining true even after  getting disconnected from internet.i want it to change to ServerValue.TIMESTAMP......................................................................................................................................**

```
>     java

    package com.example.connect;

    import android.app.Application;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ServerValue;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
    import com.squareup.picasso.OkHttp3Downloader;
    import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

    public class Connect extends Application
    {
        private FirebaseAuth auth;
        private DatabaseReference userDatabase;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

            Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(this);
            builder.downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(this, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
            Picasso built = builder.build();
            built.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
            built.setLoggingEnabled(true);
            Picasso.setSingletonInstance(built);

            if(auth!=null) {
                auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

                userDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                userDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot != null) {
                            userDatabase.child("online").onDisconnect().setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: show error logs

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom reference to Firebase that will tell you if the user is connected or not:

```
DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
        if (connected) {
            System.out.println("connected");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not connected");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
    }
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state

Keep in mind that if you don't have internet access, that does not mean that the user has been disconnected from the server, the server retains a session that will long untill it desides to disconnect the user.

This code will know when the user lost the connection to the database.